# which is lighter on the client?: UIPanGestureRecogizer continuous listening or adding and removing when needed

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

So I'm making a messaging app that allows the user to hide the keyboard on pan, with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I only want the user to hide the keyboard on vertical pan, **only** when the keyboard is showing. Here is my code:

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewPanned(_:)))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGesture.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

So my question is:

**Which option gives a lighter workload to the app?**

1. Adding the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on `viewDidLoad`, so whenever the user pans, `viewPanned` is called, **even when the keyboard isn't showing**, and it checks whether or not the keyboard is showing, or
2. Every time the keyboard shows, add the `panGesture` to the main view, and every time it hides, remove the `panGesture` from the main view, like so.

   `self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
   panGesture.delegate = nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how frequently you show the keyboard ,if you show it a lot such in sign up form it's better to add it in viewDidLoad instead of taking time (in milliseconds) to add & remove the pan , otherwise do that add / remove approach , besides it's a trade of between executing (cpu cycles) and memory (add/remove)

Answer (score 0):

Do which ever make your code cleaner.

It doesn't matter which gives a lighter workload, only optimise when there is an actual measurable problem.